# Lighted garage door pushbutton?

Tags: button

I have seen lighted garage door opener pushbuttons for wall-mounted wired garage door openers. I think there is an LED inside.

What other components are needed? What is the circuit?

Comment: You know how this works. You need to show us a schematic of the existing button, along with all relevant voltages.

Comment: just a voltage to go off would be plenty to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the open circuit voltage across the switch contacts twice (a meter in both AC and DC modes) and report back.

Don't know about new ones, but many old openers ran the control system on 24 Vac or 28 Vac.  For mine (1972-ish), the open circuit voltage is 28 Vac, and the short circuit current (switch contacts closed) is 0.63 A.  This is the coil current for the relay that starts things moving.  I have to pull almost 100 mA through the loop before I hear a hum coming from the motor head (the relay armature starting to chatter).  Because of all of this, I have a door control system that uses less than 30 mA, and runs on the open circuit switch loop.

If any of this applies to your situation, you can have two LEDs, or one LED and one rectifier diode, back to back, in series with an appropriate current limiting resistor.

Answer (score 0):

OK -- so I measured (system is from ~ 1996). There are 2 wires (red and black). Red is -18 V to Black (seems opposite to usual usage). Short circuit current is 10 mA. It requires a ~ 50 Ω short to trigger the button action (about 0.5 V across the switch or less); approaching this slowly doesn't seem to trigger.

So no other components are needed. Just a LED (with the correct polarity) across the wires (in parallel with the pushbutton) is OK. The LED's current will be about 10 mA (which is sufficiently bright), and the VF of the LED is well over 1.5 V, so the LED alone doesn't activate the button.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: it seems like a fairly clear description of how their lighted button works. how is it not an answer?